# How to pass queue-name to camel route via a variable?

Tags: dynamic, parameters, routes, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am trying to dynamically create a rabbitmq queue via camel-route.

Camel route that I have configured:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
        JacksonDataFormat jsonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(somequeue.class);
        from("direct:startRabbitMQPoint").id("rabbitMQRoute").marshal(jsonDataFormat)
                .to("rabbitmq:test.mymq.exchange?queue=test.mymq.queue&exchangeType=direct&autoDelete=false&connectionFactory=#myConnectFactory")
                .end();
}
```

This configuration does create a queue with name test.mymq.queue. However, my requirement is to pass the queue name in a variable because I want to create queues dynamically. I tried passing a parameter to the route via the route-class constructor as shown below:

public class CreateQueueRoute extends RouteBuilder {

```
private String queueName;

public CreateQueueRoute(String queueName) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
}

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
        JacksonDataFormat jsonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(somequeue.class);
        from("direct:startRabbitMQPoint").id("rabbitMQRoute").marshal(jsonDataFormat)
                .to("rabbitmq:test.mymq.exchange?queue="+queueName+"&exchangeType=direct&autoDelete=false&connectionFactory=#myConnectFactory")
                .end();
}
```

This configuration creates a queue with the name "0 0/4 * * * ?"

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass the queue-name as a parameter to the camel route?

thanks in advance

Comment: See the `toD` for dynamic endpoints: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/toD-eip.html

Comment: I also logged a ticket to see if we can make this possible with a header instead of having to use toD: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14280